# How to get sales posts from Facebook group (/feed does not return them)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I access graph.facebook.com//feed I get only the "normal" posts, but not the sales posts that I too can see in the group.

It seems that Facebook API doesn´t offers and endpoint/edge to return these. Can that be true or am I missing something?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no API for those.

Comment: I guess you are right, I´m afraid.